# Java String Replacement

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this in a file

```
<script>
Evening</script>
```

I have written a code to replace this string but it's not identifying the newline character
i,e. I want to replace above string with:

```
<h1>Done</h1>
```

code goes like this:

```
package stringreplace;
import java.io.*;

import org.omg.CORBA.Request;

public class stringreplace {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try
        {
             fr = new FileReader("G://abc.html");
             br = new BufferedReader(fr);

             String newtext="";
             String line="";

             String matchExist1 = "<script>\r\nEvening</script>";
             String newpattern = "<h1>Done</h1>";

             String matchExist2 = "</body>";
             String newpattern2 = "<script>alpha</script></body>";

             StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

             while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
             {
                int ind2 = line.indexOf(matchExist1);
                System.out.println(ind2);
                int ind3 = line.indexOf(matchExist2);
                if((ind2==-1) || (ind3==-1))
                 {
                    line = line.replaceFirst(matchExist1,newpattern);
                    line = line.replaceFirst(matchExist2,newpattern2);
                    sb.append(line+"\n");   
                 }
                //sb.append(line+"\n");
                else if((ind2!=-1) || (ind3!=-1))
                 {
                    String tag = "</body>";
                    line = line.replaceFirst("</body>",tag);
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                 }
            }
             br.close();

             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("G://abc.html");
             fw.write(sb.toString());
             fw.close();

             System.out.println("done");
             System.out.println(sb);

        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
         System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

But it is not identifying newline character.

Comment: Slightly tangential - if all you are trying to do is parse HTML, why can't you just use a XML parser (provided its XHTML)? In my experience, writing a good regex-based parser for HTML is not worth the time.

Comment: are you sure, it's "\r\n" and not just a single "\n"?

Comment: As Pavan mentioned, and by my experience, I recommend jsoup.org.

Comment: Completely tangential: why import org.omg.CORBA.Request?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are reading only one input line at a time you can hardly expect to match a pattern that spans two lines.You must first fix your read to have a least two lines in it. Once you've done that, @sterna's answer will do the trick

Comment: +1, you have seen more. But the part about the `Mutliline` flag is wrong, it does just change the behaviour of the `^` and `$` anchors. What you probably meant was the [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag, that makes the dot also matches newline characters. But this also not his problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't be sure about how your newline looks like. So I would not match for a specific sequence instead use `\s+` this is at least one whitespace character and all newline characters are included.

```
String matchExist1 = "<script>\\s+Evening</script>";
```

**Edit:**
Of course, you have to **fix at first the problem mgc described (+1)**. And then you can make use of my answer!

Comment: line.indexOf(matchExist1) won't match on a regex